# Xubuntu: Cannot unlock/wakeup when lid is closed

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, session, screen-lock

My laptop is docked with the lid closed. If I lock the session, it is impossible to wake up the system with mouse or keyboard. I must open the lid to wake it up.

How to unlock without opening the lid ?

OS: xubuntu 18 with xfce

Thanks

Comment: This is controlled by the contents of /proc/acpi/wakeup. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152403/how-do-i-make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent) for example. Note that most folks try to prevent USB wakeup, since the slightest mouse wiggle after suspension will wakeup the system.

Comment: so, use an external mouse and it will wake the system if moved/clicked